# java.net.SocketException : connection reset

Tags: java, sockets

I have read through most similar questions in Stack-overflow . But i can't find similar one.
I build one client and one server. For my client networking, i build a class which contains a socket and many relevant methods like this :

```
    public class Connector {
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private DataInputStream input;

    public Connector(int x) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        socket=new Socket("localhost",x);
    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        return socket.isConnected();
    }

    public void sendInfo(String str) throws IOException{
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.writeUTF(str);
        output.flush();
    }

    public String receiveInfo() throws IOException{
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        return input.readUTF();
    }

    public boolean loginSuccess() throws IOException{
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        return input.readBoolean();
    }
}
```

and when my client runs(the server run in my IDE),

```
    String userAccount = "VerifyAccount" + "@" + userNametf.getText() + "@" + passwordtf.getText() + "@" + i;
            connector.sendInfo(userAccount);
            if(connector.isConnected())
                System.out.println("the connector is still connected!");
            else
                System.out.println("the connector is no connected!");
            if(connector.loginSuccess()){
                System.out.println("Log in success");
            }
            else;
```

and this is my server:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
    while(true){
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
        try{
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            String tempStr = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server receive data : "+tempStr);
            String[] tempStrArray = tempStr.split("@");
            if(tempStrArray[0].equals("VerifyAccount")){
                if(UserVerification.isValid(tempStr.substring(14))==1){
                    output.writeBoolean(true);
                    output.flush();
                }
                else{}
            }
            else if(tempStrArray[0].equals("RegisterAccount")){}
            else{}
                }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

So the whole process is that the client socket connects to the server socket , 
then client send one string to the server , the server process the string , and write a boolean value back to the client , but when i call connector.LoginSuccess() , the compiler will throw an exception like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mytw0.png)

Comment: Compilers don't throw exceptions. Applications throw exceptions. You are misusing `isConnected()`. It doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It tells you the state of the socket, not the state of the connection. You connected it, it stays connected: it doesn't magically start returning false when the peer disconnects. Don't post pictures of text here, or links to them. Post the text.

Comment: If it is the case , can i ask what it was that caused the the exception of connection reset ?

Answer (score 0):

You are never closing the accepted socket. You are also attempting to read a boolean that may never be sent. And, as I said in comments, `isConnected()` doesn't do what you think it does: it doesn't magically start returning false when the peer disconnects.